# What effect does casting a variable as (void *) have?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

In a C program I see the following statement:

```
memcpypgm2ram((void*)&AppConfig.MyMACAddr, (ROM void*)SerializedMACAddress, sizeof(AppConfig.MyMACAddr));
```

**What does the (void*) case do?** This is written for the Microchip C30 compiler.

AppConfig is defined like this:

```
APP_CONFIG AppConfig;  // APP_CONFIG is obviously a structure...
```

SerializedMACAddress is defined like this:

```
static ROM BYTE SerializedMACAddress[6] = {MY_DEFAULT_MAC_BYTE1, MY_DEFAULT_MAC_BYTE2, MY_DEFAULT_MAC_BYTE3, MY_DEFAULT_MAC_BYTE4, MY_DEFAULT_MAC_BYTE5, MY_DEFAULT_MAC_BYTE6};
```

EDIT: I should have stated this before but memcpypgm2ram is defined as:
   #define memcpypgm2ram(a,b,c) memcpy(a,b,c)

so basically, `void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`

Comment: What's `memcpypgm2ram`'s full prototype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void*` is the universal data pointer type, that, when used as an argument type, denotes that a function works on "bare" memory blocks. It cannot be dereferenced.

Any other data pointer type can be implicitly converted to `void*`, so the explicit cast is probably either wrong (unnecessary), or a workaround for a broken compiler, or a shorthand to cast to `unsigned char *` (in which case it's a workaround for a broken interface).

Answer (score 1):

The cast `void *` converts a pointer of some type into a Generic Pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The memcpypgm2ram function does not need a specific type. It should be defined with the following prototype : memcpypgm2ram(void* p1, void* p2, int n);
"void *" is a cast to a generic pointer type.

The function just takes two pointers of any type and copy n bytes (in your case n=sizeof(AppConfig.MyMACAddr)) from one address to the other.

Answer (score 0):

memcpypgm2ram presumably takes a void pointer as it's argument.  C is strongly enough typed to recognize that the type of &AppConfig.MyMACAddr is (MACAddr*) and will emit a compile-time error if you don't cast it as a void*.

The point is that memcpypgm2ram is a function that works on any bytes held in memory, so it won't accept strongly typed pointers as arguments.

Comment: If conversion to `void*` makes the compiler emit an error, then the compiler is broken.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to say what was the point of using `(void *)` cast in this specific case without seeing more context (how is `memcpypgm2ram` declared?).

In C language (as well as in C++) pointer types are implicitly convertible to `void *` type, which means that in pointer conversions there's usually no reason to use an explicit cast to `void *` type. It looks like in your example all conversions are pointer conversions, so, taking into account what I said, the explicit cast to `void *` is not required.

Another possibility though is that the original pointer types are const-qualified, so the cast to `void *` was used to remove the const-qualification. However, I don't see any const-qualifications in what you provided, which means, again, that most likely that cast to `void *` is unnecessary. My guess would be that whoever put it there did it "just in case" for no real reason.

In short, the `(void *)` cast converts the pointers to `void *` type. But since that conversion would happen implicitly anyway, the cast is totally unnecessary (assuming `memcpypgm2ram` is declared with `void *` parameters).

Answer (score 0):

in this case, casting to (void *) may be used to get rid of compiler's warning.

Comment: Broken compilers' warnings, that is.